# Open bat file does not start it but opens it in editor

Tags: windows, batch-file, explorer, file-association

Since some time, when I click on BAT file in Windows Explorer (Windows 7) the BAT file is not started. Instead, the BAT file is opened in Notepad. I tried to repair this, by using Right-click to use Open With... . No luck, because this function is forbidden for system files (exe, com, bat ...). Now my question is: how to repair this odd behaviour?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. it is not general tech support.

Comment: just a hint: `assoc .bat` should return `.bat=batfile` and  `ftype batfile` should return `batfile="%1" %*`

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful,but make sure to backup registry before trying.Copy the following into Notepad,rename to .reg and double click to merge.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.bat]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bat]

@="batfile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell\open\command]

@="\"%1\" %*"
```

Alternatively,download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fcwzajb849ubgg/BatchFile.reg).

Comment: many thanks, further more I had an `UserChoice` entry in one of this registries which I had to delete